# Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting

Tags: php, apache, twig, wamp, xdebug

I have got xdebug problem while developing the website in wamp it limits caching to 256. I have tried disabling xdebug extension but after disabling I refreshed the website and it show just white screen. I have also tried increasing the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level but it crashes all website and whole website goes down.

I have no Idea what to do anymore. 
Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you are nesting 256 functions one inside the other? I'd review my software architecture instead of trying to expand the XAMP limits

Comment: Looks like you have an infinite recursion.  Somewhere in your code you've made it so that loading this template requires loading this template.

Comment: You prolly have a template that is including itself by the looks of it

Comment: the problem is that this website is made by another dev and now I am in charge for adding features and stuff like that so there is too many code to overview it

Comment: could be recursive inclusion I will try to look for that

Comment: but any ideas how to increase the size or limit or something like that

Comment: Start by locating the cached template file `369.......php`

Comment: @DatoDT Something is recursing. It's pointless increasing the limits, because it will just recurse for longer before throwing the same error.

Comment: If you disabled XDEBUG and the site still crashed then the issue is with the site code and not the tools that stand guard to warn you about coding mistakes like this. So leave the nesting level alone

Comment: @DatoDT: I doubt you can increate any limits to a number greater than *infinite*.  You're thinking about this the wrong way.  If the code is broken, don't try to break the system in a similar enough way that it goes unnoticed.  Fix the code.

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: but strange thing is that it was working day before :D it makes me go insane Islept and when I woke up it was not working

Comment: I don't think so they were not yesterday and I have not change anything connected to inclusion

Comment: I was just rumbling in html nothing really special

Comment: it is a local version actual version of the website is here https://fufala.ge

Comment: @DatoDT: Maybe someone/something else changed the deployed code, maybe some data used in conditional logic changed, maybe some configuration value used in conditional logic changed, maybe some conditional logic was time/date-dependent, etc.  "It worked yesterday", while perhaps a true statement, doesn't identify the problem.  You need to replicate the problem in your debugging.

Comment: what you are saying is a probability in 500 000 line code

Answer (score 2):

Xdebug is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. You seem to be recursively including a Twig template. Xdebug aborts your script with this error message, before PHP crashes. When you disable Xdebug, the "white screen" that you get, is PHP crashing. You can likely find evidence for that with `sudo dmesg` or in your PHP-FPM log file. It should say something akin to `segmentation fault`.

The right way of solving this, is by making sure you are not including the same template in a recursive fashion. Please note, that this could also happen through a recursive PHP variable structure that you're trying to display **with** Twig.